# Loop over image collection ee.ImageCollection to plot in geemap.Map

Tags: python, for-loop, google-earth-engine, geemap

I am accessing the GEE data catalog through `earthengine-api` in Colab. Then I would like to explore all the images from my filtered image collection before downloading.

```
# import libraries
import ee,datetime
import geemap
```

```
ee.Authenticate()
ee.Initialize()
```

```
Map = geemap.Map()
```

Filter a collection

```
roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon([['insert your coordinates']])

start = ee.Date('2023-01-01')
end = ee.Date('2023-02-01')

collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED') \
               .filterBounds(roi) \
               .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 10)) \
               .filterDate(start, end)
```

Visualize it

```
# Visualization
visualization = {'min': 0.0,
                 'max': 0.3,
                 'bands': ['B4', 'B3', 'B2']}

listOfImages = collection.toList(collection.size())
for i in range(collection.size().getInfo()):
  img = listOfImages.get(i)
  Image = img.multiply(0.0001)
  Map.addLayer(Image, visualization, 'RGB'+str(i))
Map
```

I was expecting a map where I could interact and explore the data. But I am getting the following error message.

`AttributeError:`

`Cannot add an object of type ComputedObject to the map.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `multiply` is a function for `ee.Image`s (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-multiply) not `ee.ImageCollection`s (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-imagecollection).

So make `img` an `ee.Image` in your `for` `loop` when `multiply`ing:

```
for i in range(collection.size().getInfo()):
    img = listOfImages.get(i)
    Image = ee.Image(img).multiply(0.0001)
    Map.addLayer(Image, visualization, 'RGB' + str(i))
```

Comment: The `ee.Image()` was missing. Thanks @Ori Yarden Phd!